# Trigonometry minimum value

Tags: trigonometry, optimization

If $\alpha ,  \beta$ and $\gamma$ are angles of triangle

How can we prove that $$ \cot^2(\alpha) + \cot^2(\beta) + \cot^2(\gamma) $$ has a minimum value of $1$.

I actually used the AM-GM inequality taking the product of the cotangents of the angle. I wrote them in form of sine and cosine, used sum product formula but at last got stuck unable to move ahead.

I was also wondering, can I prove the fact by calculus using derivative. Can it be done with that approach also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way of approaching this problem is by method Lagrange multipliers. Since you have the constraint $x+y+z=\pi$, you need to minimize
$$
\cot^2 x+\cot^2 y+\cot^2 z -\lambda (x+y+z-\pi)
$$
You can do the actual differentiation but by just looking at this expression you see that the extremum happens at $x=y=z$ because of the symmetry. Hence at point (and only that point) $x_0=y_0=z_0=\pi/3$ we have an extremum. On the other hand
$$
\cot \frac{\pi}{3}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}
$$
The value of our function at that point is $\cot^2 x_0+ \cot^2 y_0+\cot^2 z_0=1$. To see this is actually a minimum check that in the limit $x=0$, $y=z=\pi/2$ (which is a limit of a triangle) the value of your function is infinity.

Alternatively if you are not comfortable with Lagrange multiplier simply differentiate
$$
\cot^2 x+\cot^2 y+\cot^2(\pi-x-y)
$$
to find the same result.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

For $A+B+C=\pi,$

$\tan A+\tan B+\tan C=\tan A\tan B\tan C$

$\implies\sum_{\text{cyc}}\cot A\cot B=1$  (See [this](http://keral2008.blogspot.in/2012/02/if-abc-180-show-that-cot-cotb-cotbcotc.html))

Now use $\sum_{\text{cyc}}(\cot A-\cot B)^2\ge0$